# Passing limit 1 in SQLiteDatabase.delete() in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

//IN CONTENT PROVIDER

```
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

            int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
            SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = myDB.getWritableDatabase();
            int rowsDeleted = 0;

            switch (uriType) {
            case STUDENTS:
    //          rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(MyDBHandler.TABLE_STUDENTS, selection,  selectionArgs);
                rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(MyDBHandler.TABLE_STUDENTS, selection + " ?",  new String [] {"limit 1"});


                break;
default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return rowsDeleted;
    }
```

IN CONTENT RESOLVER

```
    private ContentProviderClient myCR;
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/"+ STUDENT_TABLE);

        public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
            myCR = 

context.getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient(CONTENT_URI);
        public boolean deleteStudent(String studentName) {  
    String selection = "sName = " + studentName +  " LIMIT 1";
        rowsDeleted = myCR.delete(CONTENT_URI, selection,null);

//also tried this
String selection = "sName = " + studentName ;
rowsDeleted = myCR.delete(CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().encodedQuery("limit 1").build(), selection,null);
```

There a student table from which i'm deleting entries based on names and since there can be many students with same name i want to restrict delete function to DELETE just the 1st entry only. Please don't tell me delete using Student Reg No.

Answer (score 0):

The SQLite compiled into Android does not allow a `LIMIT` clause for `DELETE` statements.

You have to do a `SELECT` with a `LIMIT 1` (or read only the first returned record), and use the returned ID to delete using student Reg No.